# owl - protege not inferring correctly? how to define precisely a class "vegetarian"?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, owl, protege

I have been stuck for two days now trying to understand why the following scenario isn't working:

screenshots here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4677548/screenshots.html

I have a VegetarianFood class (subclass of Food) that is equivalent to "Food and (Eggs or MilkAndDerivates or VeganFood)" as you can see in the screenshot number 1

The VeganFood class, on turn, is equivalent to other classes (NutsAndSeeds, Cereals, Fruit, etc...)
screenshot 2

as you can see there are two individuals (cheddar cheese and cashew) created as MilkAndDerivates and NutsAndSeeds 
screenshot 3
and they are correctly inferred as VegetarianFood and VeganFood member

Then I created two individuals as recipes, one only with cashew (PastaVega) and one with both cheddar chese and cashew (PastaVege), using the object property hasIngredient 
screenshot 4 and 5

and they have been inferred as Recipe...BUT none falls into the category of VegatarianRecipe and VeganRecipe, defined as follows
screenshot 6 and 7

I have no clues, Why they are not inferred as VegetarianRecipe (or vegan)??What am I missing?

Edit:

If I change VegetarianRecipe (or vegan) from 
"Recipe and (hasIngredient ONLY VegetarianFood)"

to 
"Recipe and (hasIngredient SOME VegetarianFood)"

screenshot 8

the recepies individuals are showed, but of course this is not what I am trying to do, as in this way it will include recipes with mixed meat and vegetarianFood.
So how to define a vegetarianrecipe and veganrecipe class to allow the reasoner to infer correctly when a recipe is vegetarian or vegan????

Comment: The "link" you gave to the screenshots will only work on your computer.  You need to upload them to something like imgur.com first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have hit upon a consequence of the fact that OWL reasoning uses an open-world assumption.

The reason your `PastaVege` recipe is not inferred to be a `VegetarianRecipe` is that, although the ingredients that you explicitly list in the recipe are indeed all `VegeratianFood` instances, it could well be that some currently unknown ingredient of your recipe is not a vegetarian food.

Since your constraint on `VegetarianRecipe` is that *all* ingredients should be VegetarianFoods (not just the ones we currently know about), it cannot be definitively concluded (in an open world) that your recipe is indeed a `VegetarianRecipe`.

There are a number of ways to deal with this, but none really do exactly what you want - you need to approach it from a slightly different angle.

Without going into the exact modeling details: although it is quite difficult to infer if a recipe is vegetarian given your current model, it is relatively simple to infer if a recipe is not vegetarian; any recipe that has at least one non-vegetarian ingredient is a non-vegetarian recipe.

An alternative approach is that you create a closed set of (vegetarian) ingredients (using an OWL enumerated class via the `oneOf` constraint), but that is a significant change to your model, and of course it is tedious to have to list all possible ingredients in this fashion.