# Reasoning: Individuals to classes in OWL

Tags: owl, protege, reasoning

I'm trying to reason with OWL in Protege. I have individual that should be classified to vegetarian or meat pizza, based on the topping. It works for meat with *hasTopping some NotVeg*, but it does not work with vegetarian for *hasTopping only Vegetarian*, they are just classified in the superclass *Pizza*. The classes are disjoint and I have no clue why it did not work.

Can anybody help?

I used the following ontology:

```
Prefix: : <http://www.semanticweb.org/inference/pizza#>
Prefix: owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
Prefix: rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
Prefix: xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
Prefix: xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
Prefix: rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
Prefix: untitled-ontology-140: <http://www.semanticweb.org/inference/pizza#>

Ontology: <http://www.semanticweb.org/inference/pizza>

ObjectProperty: untitled-ontology-140:hasTopping
    Domain: 
        untitled-ontology-140:MeatPizza or untitled-ontology-140:VegPizza
    Range: 
        untitled-ontology-140:Topping

Class: untitled-ontology-140:Topping

Class: untitled-ontology-140:VegPizza
    SubClassOf: 
        untitled-ontology-140:Pizza,
        untitled-ontology-140:hasTopping only untitled-ontology-140:Vegetarian
    DisjointWith: 
        untitled-ontology-140:MeatPizza

Class: untitled-ontology-140:MeatPizza
    SubClassOf: 
        untitled-ontology-140:Pizza,
        untitled-ontology-140:hasTopping some untitled-ontology-140:NotVeg
    DisjointWith: 
        untitled-ontology-140:VegPizza

Class: untitled-ontology-140:NotVeg
    SubClassOf: 
        untitled-ontology-140:Topping
    DisjointWith: 
        untitled-ontology-140:Vegetarian

Class: untitled-ontology-140:Pizza
    SubClassOf: 
        untitled-ontology-140:hasTopping some untitled-ontology-140:Topping

Class: untitled-ontology-140:Vegetarian
    SubClassOf: 
        untitled-ontology-140:Topping
    DisjointWith: 
        untitled-ontology-140:NotVeg

Individual: untitled-ontology-140:PizzaC
    Facts:  
        untitled-ontology-140:hasTopping  untitled-ontology-140:Meat

Individual: untitled-ontology-140:PizzaB
    Facts:  
        untitled-ontology-140:hasTopping  untitled-ontology-140:Tomato,
        untitled-ontology-140:hasTopping  untitled-ontology-140:Meat

Individual: untitled-ontology-140:PizzaA
    Facts:  
        untitled-ontology-140:hasTopping  untitled-ontology-140:Tomato

Individual: untitled-ontology-140:Tomato
    Types: 
        untitled-ontology-140:Vegetarian

Individual: untitled-ontology-140:Meat
    Types: 
        untitled-ontology-140:NotVeg
```

Comment: As always, the **Open World Assumption** - one of the characteristics of OWL. You should read something about it, then you'll know the reason and can give the answer here by yourself :D

Comment: Hint: for a given pizza type, it's not enough that toppings are vegetarian, it must also be inferrable that vegetarian toppings are non meaty and that no non vegetarian toppings apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [owl - protege not inferring correctly? how to define precisely a class "vegetarian"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366754/owl-protege-not-inferring-correctly-how-to-define-precisely-a-class-vegetari)

Comment: I disjoint the classes of the toppings --> inferable that vegetarian toppings are not meaty.
But how can it be inferable that no not vegetarian toppings are applied? I tried to use the owl:oneOf, as mentioned in the link from Jeen. I defined the topping vegetarian as _Equivalent To {Tomato}_ (the only instance) and the some meaty toppings. But it did not help. is there another way how I can model it? I could not find a proper tutorial.